# How to change the PHP file extension using .htaccess file on GoDaddy Linux Hosting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following .htaccess rules to modify the PHP file extensions to HTML:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

I placed the .htaccess file as well as two PHP files (page1.php and page2.php) in the root.

When I try to access the PHP files using the html extension instead (page1.html or page2.html) I get the 404 error message stating the page cannot be found.

Could you please guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

when you will access page1.html the system will look for: page1.php