# .htaccess RewriteRule display php as cfm

Tags: php, .htaccess

The current .htaccess not working :

```
RewriteRule ^search\.cfm?q=(.*)$ index.php?current=search&q=$1 [NC,L]
```

current syntax is:

```
index.php?current=search&q=stackoverflow
```

New syntax :

```
search.cfm?q=stackoverflow
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the PHP file extension using .htacess file on GoDaddy Linux Hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897353/how-to-change-the-php-file-extension-using-htacess-file-on-godaddy-linux-hostin)

Comment: i want this result : search.cfm?q=stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you asked for, this should be what you need.

```
RewriteRule ^search\.cfm$ index.php?current=search [NC,L,QSA]
```

The QSA tag is going to append the `q=` Query String back to your `.php` file.