# Using .htaccess or Apache Handler

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, file, web

I want my ***shared*** web server to process ".ncs" files just like ".php" files.
I know this can be easily done by adding an entry in Apache Handler. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php

But as I have mentioned that I am using shared hosting, any changes made by me on Apache Handler will not work. Those lists are just for reference. I opened a ticket in my website provider's support panel and they told me that I should use .htaccess file for that. But I am unable to understand that how I may use .htaccess file to process **.ncs** files just like **.php** files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the PHP file extension using .htaccess file on GoDaddy Linux Hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897353/how-to-change-the-php-file-extension-using-htaccess-file-on-godaddy-linux-hosti)

Comment: My two cents would be *not* use .htaccess if at all possible. The need to turn on Allow Override causes overhead of scanning filesystem and is not desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a AddType handler on the htaccess of the root of your server:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .ncs
```

BUT if you're running PHP as CGI, you need to use AddHandler too:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .ncs
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .ncs
```

Comment: This is what my .htaccess file of root directory has:
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

**Where to add your suggested code snippet?**

Comment: At the complete begining of the file.

Comment: I have tried it. But still nothing. The PHP server is still not evaluating statements of the pinfo.ncs file.

Comment: try with x-httpd-php5, sounds weird but the server could be configured differently.