# Rewriting extension PHP to XML using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, plesk

I have a sitemap in PHP sitemap-latest.php and i want to change the extension to `.xml` without affecting the file and content in it.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sitemap-latest.xml$ sitemap-latest.php [L] #NoEffect
RewriteRule ^sitemap-latest\.php$ sitemap-latest.xml [R=301,L] #Redirect to folders https://www.example.com/var/www/vhosts/mirrorblogs.com/website1/sitemap-latest.xml
RewriteRule ^sitemap-latest.php$ sitemap-latest.xml [L] #404 error for both php and xml
```

But nothing is happening. `example.com/sitemap-latest.php` not changing to `example.com/sitemap-latest.xml`

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897353/how-to-change-the-php-file-extension-using-htaccess-file-on-godaddy-linux-hosti ?

Comment: @dev_mustafa it is similar things. he replacing all link and i replacing only one file.

Comment: The rules look OKish, though certainly details could be altered. But if you say "nothing is happening" (whatever that means _exactly_ ) then maybe the rules are not getting applied at all. That would be the case if 1. the rewriting module is not present at all (not laoded/activated/not an apache http server) or of 2. you placed the rules in the wrong location or 3. you forgot to enable the interpretation of such rules by means of the `AllowOverride` directive.

Comment: _"example.com/sitemap-latest.php not changing to example.com/sitemap-latest.xml"_ - that is not what that RewriteRule does, it does the exact _opposite_ - when the _incoming_ request is for `/sitemap-latest.xml`, then it will internally rewrite that to `sitemap-latest.php`

Comment: If you have links pointing to `example.com/sitemap-latest.php` somewhere that you can't change, or you want to redirect clients that request that "old" URL for some reason, _to_ the `.xml` version - then you need a rule that performs an external redirect first.

Comment: @arkascha other rules are in my `.htaccess` is working fine

Comment: @CBroe you mean `RewriteRule ^sitemap-latest.php$ sitemap-latest.xml [L]` like this?. I also tried this. same nothing happening.

Comment: Did you put that rule directly under those two existing RewriteConds? (Meaning, is it the _first_ rule that follows those?) If so, then of course nothing will happen in this particular situation - those conditions prevent the rule from applying, when the requested URL directly matches an existing file or folder. And since you _have_ a `sitemap-latest.php` that actually exists here, no rewriting would be done.

Comment: Plus for an external redirect, you'd also need the `R` flag.

Comment: @CBroe `RewriteRule ^sitemap-latest.php$ sitemap-latest.xml [R,L]` along with two existing RewriteConds. Nothing happened

Comment: Well what did I just explain about those RewriteConds?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^sitemap-latest\.php$ sitemap-latest.xml [R=301,L]` alone this redirect to `https://www.example.com/var/www/vhosts/mirrorblogs.com/website1/sitemap-latest.xml`

instead of `example.com/sitemap-latest.xml`

Comment: Please share more details. What's the expected behaviour? "not changing to" - what does that mean? A RewriteRule is usually not changing any URL, but solely how the server processes it. Also, please remove the irrelevant tags - or explain how your problem is related to cPanel and Plesk